# Set Cluster Tolerance in FME

Tags: fme-form, cluster-tolerance

I am new to FME and need to perform an intersect with a specific cluster tolerance. In ArcGIS Pro you can set the cluster tolerance during an intersect (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) but I don't know how I can reproduce this in FME? The intersector does not have this option and there is no "cluster tolerance" transformer. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're talking about two different operations here. You mentioned the intersect tool in ArcGIS but the clipper tool in FME. What are you trying to accomplish? For intersects, I would use the AreaOnAreaOverlayer. Possibly precede that with an anchoredSnapper or just a snapper. Can you elaborate a bit on your workflow? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Fezter I meant to type "Intersector" not "Clipper", my apologies. And I think I found a comparable solution: Intersect my feature layers THEN perform an anchor snapper making the original layers the anchors and the intersected polygons the candidate. I would need both layers to be the the anchor, however I am not sure if this is logical?

Comment: NearestNeighbor can also be used https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/28816/determining-nearest-neighbors.html

Comment: Right now, FME has no "tolerance" concept in its Intersector or Clipper. But what folks do is use the Snapper or AnchoredSnapper before or after to accomplish similar results.  In your case it seems reasonable that you'd use the AnchoredSnapper, but you may also get away with only using the SNapper and putting only the results in, depending on what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out FME 2018, this has been added in some transformers including the "Intersector".

Below is the text from the Intersector's help on FME.

Tolerance:
The minimum distance between geometries in 2D before they are considered equal, in ground units. If the tolerance is None, the geometries must be exactly identical to be considered equal. If the tolerance is Automatic, a tolerance will be automatically computed based on the location of the input geometries. Additionally, a custom tolerance may be used.